# Insert into select using some distinct fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a script that will insert a record back into a table where some data has already been removed. Each record removed has a `NUM` field, and a `VERS` field, which when read together, are unique. How can I form my insert query to properly match these?

So far, this is what I have, although I know it won't work. `#DHA` is a temp table where I'm staging the data being removed.

```
INSERT INTO db1.dbo.records 
            ( 
                        num, 
                        vers, 
                        activity, 
                        USER, 
                        comments 
            ) 
SELECT (distinct num, vers), 
       'Document Activity Archived', 
       'ADMIN', 
       'Contact the HelpDesk for history before 1/1/2011' 
FROM   #dha
```

Comment: what do you mean by it won't work?

Comment: Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `select distinct`:

```
insert into DB1.dbo.RECORDS (NUM, VERS, ACTIVITY, USER, COMMENTS) 
    select distinct NUM, VERS, 'Document Activity Archived', 'ADMIN',
           'Contact the HelpDesk for history before 1/1/2011'
    from #DHA;
```

The `distinct` in `select distinct` applies to all the columns in the `select`.  All the rest are constant, so that seems to be what you are looking for.